# Get enqueued_at inside scheduled Sidekiq job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have scheduled a job

```
Worker.perform_at(time, args)
```

When this job is eventually performed, is there a way to find out the original time that was scheduled?

<s>Writing the question helped me come up with this solution, but I'm not sure if it works or if it is a good solution. Inside the worker:</s>

```
this_job = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job(self.jid)
this_job.enqueued_at
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want some data inside a Worker, you pass it in as an argument:

```
Worker.perform_at(time, Time.now.to_f, *args)
```